# How to find out new index of the element in a vector after using std::unique

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, unique

In the following function, impObj argument currently points to a particular index in myVec and after using std::unique I want to update impObj to point to the same MyClass instance in vector (or the instance which was sequentially equal to original)

```
void RemoveSequentialDuplicates(std::vector<MyClass>& myVec, int& impObj)
{
    auto itrLast = std::unique(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), [](const MyClass& first, const MyClass& second) -> bool {
       return first == second;
    });
    myVec.erase(itrLast, myVec.end());
}
```

Basically what I want is -
Input1 - [A, A, B, B, D, A], impObj = 5
Output1 - [A, B, D, A] impObj = 3

Input2 - [A, B, B, B, A, A, C], impObj = 2
Output2 - [A, B, A, C] impObj = 1

Use of std::unique is not mandatory, we can use any other way also.

One way to do it is -

```
void RemoveSequentialDuplicates(std::vector<MyClass>& myVec, int& index)
{
    int leftIndex = 0, rightIndex = 1;
    auto itrLast = std::unique(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), [&leftIndex, &rightIndex, &impObj](const MyClass& first, const MyClass& second) -> bool {
        bool equals = false;
        if (first == second)
            equals = true;
        else
            leftIndex++;

        if(impObj == rightIndex)
            impObj = leftIndex;

        rightIndex++;
        return equals;
    });
    myVec.erase(itrLast, myVec.end());
}
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Note: I want to keep the order of the elements same

Comment: Get the value at index `index`. Use `std::unique` and `std::erase` as "normal". Then [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) the value iterator and calculate the index to return.

Comment: By the way, even in your old `RemoveDuplicates` you don't need to pass a predicate function, as the default will use normal equality exactly as you do. `auto itrLast = std::unique(myVec.begin(), myVec.end());` should work just as well.

Comment: The 'value' can reappear in myVec right? because std::unique will only remove sequentially equal elements. Example [A, A, B, B, D, A] after std::unique will result in [A, B, D, A]. So, if my earlier index was 5 and I want to it be updated to 3 after std::unique. With your suggestion I guess it will get updated to 0. Please correct me If I am missing something.

Comment: @Mukund no, you have it right. If you want the new `index` to be 3 instead of 0, then you will have to write your own code to erase the duplicates the way you want. After each erasure of an element, if that element's index was below `index` then decrement `index` by 1.

Comment: Instead of modifying the original vector you can create and modify a vector of references, `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MyClass>>` so your original vector is unchanged, and the vector of references becomes a view of your vector with unique elements.

Comment: @Mukund: Your general strategy of using the using the comparison functor to try to keep track of things is not a good one, as your code basically assumes that the implementation is going in a particular direction (first to last). While the function does take a forward-iterator, versions that act on bidirectional iterators could go in the opposite direction.

Comment: This is [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please explain logic and more details. Maybe it is possible to calculate new index instead updating it as `std::unique` is done? Also what should happen when given index was deleted? Equivalent should be returned or nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Details are missing, but it could be done by spiting operation into two steps:

- before `impObj` (equivalent)
- and from `impObj` (equivalent)

```cpp
void RemoveSequentialDuplicates(std::vector<MyClass>& myVec, int& impObj)
{
    // find first item equal to impObj, lower_bound is naive approach 
    auto firstObj = std::lower_bound(begin(myVec), end(myVec), myVec[impObj]);

    auto before = std::unique(begin(myVec), firstObj);
    impObj = std::distance(begin(myVec), before);
    auto newEnd = std::unique_copy(firstObj, end(myVec), before);
    myVec.erase(newEnd, myVec.end());
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/c8Ysj6j45

Note use of `std::lower_bound` is a quick first choice. Depending on exact scenario there are better choices. [Possible improvement](https://godbolt.org/z/xoTj1Msn8).

### Disclaimer

This was not specified in question so code assumes that:

- vector is not empty
- value of `impObj` is in bounds of `myVec`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove duplicates from container consider using std::list instead of std::vector like so:

```
std::list<int> values{ 1,1,5,5,7 };
values.sort(); 
values.unique();
```

Note that we use the sort() function because the unique() function only erase element that are next to each other.

Also if you want to use your class in here it must contain operator <=> which is in c++20 and above like so:

```
struct myclass {
    std::strong_ordering operator<=>(myclass& other) {
        return this->x <=> other.x;
    }

    int x;
};
```

Comment: Nice suggestions, but they do nothing to answer the OP's actual question that was asked. Please post only *relevant* answers.

Comment: I think it's valid to suggest a different data type with iterator stability

Comment: This answer doesn't work, because if the item referenced by the iterator is one that has a duplicate, it may be that one which is removed from the list. So the iterator will be invalid.